# Log out from windows authentication application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I want to develop a webapplication where the user can login automaticly with the data from the active directory or logout to get a form where the user can enter other user data to login as another user.
I set in the web.config the

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

But then I am always loged in. How can I log out and open a simple form to enter user data of another user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't *logout* with Windows authentication, that's the whole idea of this type of authentication: you log into Windows and from now on it is a Single Sign On. You will need to open the browser under another user.

If you want to enable this functionality you could use forms authentication against AD with impersonation.

Comment: If you're accessing the site from a device that is not part of the domain (like an Android tablet in our case) then the AD login works similar to the forms login where it prompts for userid and password.  In that case it does make sense to let the user logout.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get this to work but it only works for IE, not FireFox or otheres that I am aware of.

```
<input id="LogoutButton" type="button" value="Log Out" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#LogoutButton").bind("click", function () {


            try {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    alert("You have been logged off from the website");
                    document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", "false");
                    window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
                    if (top.location != location) {
                        top.location.href = ".";


                    }
                    window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
                }

            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("This feature requires IE 6.0 SP1 or above. " + "Please close all browser windows in order to complete the logout process.");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work in IE 11. I think this is very old answer and might be working in old ie version.